# How to add custom property and extend DocumentInitialProps type in _document?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm a beginner in Typescript. I'm working on a Next.js TypeScript project. Basically, what I'm trying to do is to pass a `userCurrency` value from the server side, to the client via `body` tag. I'm working on the `_document.tsx` file.
The issue is that I'm getting this error

[image]

What I gather from the error message is that `userCurrency` does not exist on `DocumentInitialProps`, and referring to other Stack Overflow posts I'm trying to extend/add an additional property `userCurrency` to the `DocumentInitialProps`.

As you can see, I created the `NewDocumentInitialProps`. However, the error is still there.
What am I doing wrong? How do I add a custom property to `DocumentInitialProps`?

```
import { Fragment } from "react";

import Document, {
  DocumentContext,
  Html,
  Head,
  Main,
  NextScript,
  DocumentInitialProps,
} from "next/document";

declare type NewDocumentInitialProps = DocumentInitialProps & {
  userCurrency?: string;
};

export default class CustomDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(
    ctx: DocumentContext
  ): Promise<NewDocumentInitialProps> {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return {
      ...initialProps,
      ...{ userCurrency: "USD" },
    };
  }

  render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          {
            <>
              <link rel="icon" href="/favicon_dev.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
            </>
          }
        </Head>
        <body data-currency={this.props.userCurrency}>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please paste your code as text, not images.

Comment: In your first code example, you are inside a functional component. Props are passed as an object through the first parameter of your function, not with `this.props` (use with classes).

Comment: I have posted the code. Actually the code works, I'm able to see the `this.props.userCurrency` value present in the body tag, in the DOM. It is the typescript compiler that is complaining about the type. 
Refer to line 17, it says `export default class CustomDocument`
Is that a functional component?

Comment: Oops, I saw incorrectly through the picture, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply typing the return type of `getInitialProps` isn't enough to properly type `this.props` in the `render` function. You need to pass `NewDocumentInitialProps` as a generics to the extended `Document` type instead, when declaring your class.

```
type NewDocumentInitialProps = DocumentInitialProps & {
    userCurrency?: string;
};

export default class CustomDocument extends Document<NewDocumentInitialProps> {
    //...
}
```

This will also properly type `getInitialProps`'s return type too, so you don't have to explicitly do it yourself.